# Given $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, what is the pdf of $Z=XY$?

Tags: probability, transformation

[image]

I approached the problem as following:

$f_{Z}(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(X=\frac{z}{y},Y=y)dy$

However, according to the textbook, the problem should be solved as below:

$f_{Z}(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f_{X}(X=\frac{z}{y}) f_{Y}(Y=y) dy$

Why do we use the marginal pdfs multiplied, instead of the joint pdf? They are equivalent when $X$ & $Y$ are independent, but when they are not doesn't it make more sense to use the joint distribution of $X$ & $Y$ in the integral, since that would account for any dependence?

I am looking to understand this conceptually. Any insights would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do we use the marginal pdfs multiplied, instead of the joint pdf?

We should not (hence either your book is wrong or you took a formula valid in the discrete setting for a formula valid in the continuous setting).

In full generality, if $Z=XY$, then
$$
f_Z(z)=\int f_{X,Y}(y^{-1}z,y)y^{-1}\mathrm dy.
$$
In your case,
$$
f_Z(z)=\int_0^\infty y^{-2}z\mathrm e^{-z-z/y}\mathrm dy\,\mathbf 1_{z\gt0}=\left[\mathrm e^{-z-z/y}\,\mathbf 1_{z\gt0}\right]_{y=0}^{y=+\infty}=\mathrm e^{-z}\mathbf 1_{z\gt0}.
$$

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. Where did the extra $y^{-1}$ come from though? Is it from the Jacobian: $J(y^{-1}z,y)$? That must have been what I was missing.

Comment: Exactly. The Jacobian matrix is $J=[[1/y,-z/y^2][0,1]]$, with determinant $|J|=1/y$.

Answer (score 1):

We could alternately find the cdf of $Z$, and differentiate. For $F_Z(z)$, we integrate the joint density over the part of the first quadrant which is under the curve $xy=z$. This can be expressed as the iterated integral
$$\int_0^\infty \left(\int_{y=0}^{z/x}xe^{-x(y+1)}\,dy\right)\,dx.$$
The integration poses no difficulty.

Comment: There is less confusion with this alternative so I like it. But do you know any intuitive explanation of why in my problem description the marginal pdfs are used instead of the joint pdf?

Comment: Not really. Here is something not very useful. Suppose in my cdf version we do not actually integrate, since it might be difficult. We can **set up** the integral, and then differentiate under the integral sign. The expression we get will end up using the integrals that give the marginals. The formula for differentiation under the integral sign has some intuitive content.